# How to get value of a dict

Tags: python

I'm new to python.
I'm using an api that returns me this dict, I'd like to know how can I get the value 'Usuário Ativo'

```
{('[Usuários].[Usuários].[Usuario1]', '[LoginInfo].[LoginInfo].[Validacao]'): {'Value': 'Usuário Ativo'}, ('[Usuários].[Usuários].[Usuario2]', '[LoginInfo].[LoginInfo].[Validacao]'): {'Value': 'OK'}}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the expected 'value'?

Comment: OP mentioned it in the question @KeroppiMomo *I'd like to know how can I get the value 'Usuário Ativo'*

Comment: One is expected to show some evidence of having *tried* to solve the problem being asked about.

Comment: oh ok sorry....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print(your_dict[('[Usuários].[Usuários].[Usuario1]', '[LoginInfo].[LoginInfo].[Validacao]')]['Value'])
```

will print what you want.

That's a pretty weird dict.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract all values from dict using dict.values. then you will get values easily.

For an example:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
dicti = {('[Usuários].[Usuários].[Usuario1]', '[LoginInfo].[LoginInfo].[Validacao]'): {'Value': 'Usuário Ativo'}, ('[Usuários].[Usuários].[Usuario2]', '[LoginInfo].[LoginInfo].[Validacao]'): {'Value': 'OK'}};

values = dicti.values()
print(values) 
for v in values:
  if v['Value'] == "Usuário Ativo":
    print(v)
```

Dict.values converts all values in array. then you can easily find whatever you want.

Comment: How do you know the one you want is the first one in the list?

Comment: Why not just use `for v in values:`?  Don't really care about the index.  Then again, you could just print the value you want w/ any searching at all.

Comment: didn't work... 'TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable'